# Performance Point, Dashboard Designer

Tags: performancepoint, dashboard-designer

1. I am brand new to this product. Microsoft has some good free videos...but I am looking for a site where I can ask question about 'how to', or post problems..any recommendations?

(http://www.microsoft.com/business/performancepoint/resources/training.aspx)

2. Just in case this is a good site for that...

I want to bring in a sql table to dashboard designer, and produce a scorecard based on 83 operational metrics across 12 divisions... I have a simple table schema:

key, metric_ID, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, CalendarWeek, Year, Entered, Updated)

I have sql jobs that crawl to multiple databases and write back the base data weekly. The idea is that I would let the dashboard designer produce the actual metric, based on the metric needs.

eg. for hotline performance closed calls on the first call, over calls received:
 (45, 16, 786, 1345,null,null,null,1,2009, 1/5/2009 6am, null)

786/1345 = 58% against an operational target of 50% .. so the kpi would be green.

my problem is;

1. when I create a scorecard using the tabluar wizard, I just get a scorecard listing the fields as rows (786, 1345, blank, blank, blank); with Actual and Target as the columns... how do I do the calculation of the metric?..or do I need to expand my sql table to actually DO the math for the metric??...
2. I dont quite get the concept of dimensionality yet...the dimensions are the Entered and Updated dates...not quite what I need..i think...

soo...how do I structure my sql table to bring in these metrics, and how do I 'dimension' the connector for dashboard designer to do the metric calculation?

Answer (score 0):

I would do the calculation on your database side.  Then it's simple to just pull the caculated value into the dashboard.  Dashboard Designer isn't the best at doing calculations (beyond normal aggregations like sum, average, etc).